# What happened to my file after this 'mv' command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I was moving my private key file (for ssl) but I used a wrong syntax.

I wanted to move it in a folder named 'ssl'

The wrong command syntax I typed is:

```
sudo mv private.key /ssl
```

(There was no ssl directory in the path)

My question is:

Where is my file? What happened to it? :sarcasm

Comment: The file is now at `/ssl`.

Comment: There was no ssl directory

Comment: Right. You renamed the file "ssl" and moved it to the root directory. You'll see it if you type `ls /ssl`.

Comment: It seems that the system created a file called ssl

Comment: Yes, I Am sorry due to a name conflict I wasn't able to see the file. I thought I lost it. You can delete this stupi*d question if you want. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No need to delete it. People have spent some time answering it. Just accept the answer from Kent and move on...

Comment: Perfect. Accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `/ssl` directory, your `private.key` will be moved to root directory (`/`) and named with `ssl`.